# DecimalFormat rounding gives different result than BigDecimal rounding

Tags: java

The following code gives -1 for BigDecimal and -0 for DecimalFormat. Why is there a difference? I would expect both to give -1

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(-0.0009).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    System.out.println(df.format(-0.0009));
```

Decimal format seems to return correct/expected result when 0.000 is used but gives wrong/unexpected result for 0, 0.0, 0.00 patterns

Comment: this may give you a better view on the question - https://onlinegdb.com/sVW0p_Nq9

Comment: Comments moved to [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237614/discussion-between-tyronne-and-socowi).

Answer (score 0):

This is because .setScale & setRoundingMode working in different ways

SetScale function Usage:-

```
 * Returns a {@code BigDecimal} whose scale is the specified
 * value, and whose unscaled value is determined by multiplying or
 * dividing this {@code BigDecimal}'s unscaled value by the
 * appropriate power of ten to maintain its overall value.  If the
 * scale is reduced by the operation, the unscaled value must be
 * divided (rather than multiplied), and the value may be changed;
 * in this case, the specified rounding mode is applied to the division.



setScale(0) rounds 0.00009  to 1
setScale(1) rounds 0.00009  to 0.1
setScale(2) rounds 0.00009  to 0.01
setScale(3) rounds 0.00009  to 0.01
```

With DecimalFormat Number is rounded & digits are shown as per the format size is mentioned.

```
 DecimalFormat("0.00") makes 0.009 to 0.01
 DecimalFormat("0.0")  makes 0.009 to 0.0 (rounding was 0.001)
 DecimalFormat("0")  makes 0.009 to 0 (rounding was 0.001)
```

DecimalFormat("0.000")  makes 0.009 to 0.009 (rounding was not needed)

Comment: This is answer is even more confusing. You said »*`0.009 … (rounding was 0.001)`*«. Why should `0.009` ever be "rounded" to `0.001`?

Comment: the "strange behavior" in that particular case is reproduced with negative number and FLOOR - positive numbers work as expected
When we reverce to CEILING the positive number rounding (0.0009) will give 0 where 1 is expected.
Also note that setscale is used with explicit RoundingMode - and the question is why DF returns this unexpected (wrong) value

Comment: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");

df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

System.out.println(df.format(-0.0009));  // this gives 0???

System.out.println(df.format(-1.0009)); // this works as expected giving -2
I think your claims on how DF works are incorrect